# Turn developer mode off in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I need some help, my websites are showing the key after the url. So i thought it is still in developer mode and need to be turned into production mode.

I checked the magento file in folder bin, but can't find a thing. Please check:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
echo 'bin/magento must be run as a CLI application';
exit(1);
}
try {
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
echo 'Autoload error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit(1);
}
try {
$handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
$application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
$application->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
while ($e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    echo "\n\n";
    $e = $e->getPrevious();
}
exit(Cli::RETURN_FAILURE);
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "showing the key after the url"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to check a wrong file. The Magento mode is set in the **`app/etc/env.php`** file.

There are two ways to set the production mode for the website:

**Method 1:** Open the **`app/etc/env.php`** file and change:

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
```

to

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
```

**Method 2:** Open the terminal and change directory to the document root of your Magento folder. Then run the following command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that it is in production mode

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that bin/magento is empty. You get an error when you run the deploy:mode:set command?

Switch to production mode:

```
rm -rf /website-root/generated/metadata/* /website-root/generated/code/*
```

then

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Hide URL key:

```
  php bin/magento config:set admin/security/use_form_key 0
```

Comment: I there a file where i can hide the URL key? because i don't know where and how to run the command.